# deleting a member registered in the members database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database setup to register members for a members only area of a site. I can echo all of the registered members with a checkbox so that I can choose to delete an individual member from an admin page, but I cant seem to figure out how to get the member chosen to be deleted when the submit button is clicked. I have tried to do it on a single page and on a 2 page process, first page lists the members with the checkbox which works to the point of choosing the member to be deleted, the difficulty I seem to be having is getting the members detail passed to the delete section of the code. Could anyone assist me please.

here is the delete_user.php which lists the members with a checkbox

```
   <?php 
    include_once 'db_connect.php';
    include_once 'functions.php';
    sec_session_start();

    //display users info with checkbox to delete  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `members` LIMIT 0, 30 ";  
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    { 
        echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' .$row['username'] . '" name="delete[]" />';     
//      echo '<input type='checkbox' value='' .$row['adminid'] . '' name='delete[]' />';
        echo ' ' .$row['username'];
        echo ' ' .$row['email'];
        echo '<br />';  
    }
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Delete Member</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <form>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" formaction="delete_user.inc.php" formmethod="POST" value="Delete User">
          </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

here is the process page delete_user.inc.php

```
   <?php
   include_once 'db_connect.php';
   include_once 'functions.php';
   sec_session_start();
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")    {          
        foreach($_POST['delete'] as $delete_user)
        {   
            $sql = "DELETE FROM members WHERE memberid = '$delete_user'";      
            mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die ('die now');          
        }        
        echo 'user has been deleted.<br />';   
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you are rendering your checkboxes outside your form

Comment: The form is also a GET form and not a POST form.

Comment: Also, you aren't sanitizing the data, so there's an opportunity for SQL injection.

Comment: Ghost does that mean i need to put my php code within the form tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must render your checkboxes inside your form:

```
<?php 
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';
sec_session_start();

//display users info with checkbox to delete  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `members` LIMIT 0, 30 ";  
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Delete Member</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form type="POST" action="delete_user.inc.php">
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
            <label>
            <?php echo $row['username']; ?> - <?php echo $row['email']; ?>
            <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['memberid']; ?>" name="delete[]" />
            </label>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Delete User" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then on your delete process:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {          
    foreach($_POST['delete'] as $delete_user) {   
        $sql = "DELETE FROM members WHERE memberid = ?";      
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $delete_user);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
    echo 'user has been deleted.<br />';           
}

?>
```

Comment: I have used the code you edited for me, and I will not pretend to fully understand the $stmt or the bind_param, unfortunately it 1/ doesnt line up the echoed data to the left of the page now and 2/ still wont delete the chosen member

Comment: @user3370876 i just used prepared statements instead, wait i revised something, can you try it again

Comment: @user3370876 i edited the `$row['memberid']` a while ago on the first file (the form), it will delete based on id instead kindly try it again

Comment: Hi Ghost still appears to be doing the same, where you have binded the paramater 'i' to the $delete_user should the $sql be memberid = 'i'"

Comment: @user3370876 i used `i` because i assumed `memberid` is an `int` right?

Comment: yes int(11), im new to php only been using it and database since january

Comment: @user3370876 what does `print_r($POST['delete'])` contain?

Comment: where would i put that?

Comment: @user3370876 you need to put that after `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`, after submission, check the values

Comment: I have put the print statement where you said and im getting no values

Comment: @user3370876 just make sure while testing, check at least one checkbox, since they is no validation, if should fail when no checkboxes are checked? in this code, did it rendered the checkboxes?

Comment: yes all the checkboxes were rendered, all the database info were echoed, just doesnt seem to be passing the chosen data to the delete code on submit

Comment: @user3370876 so when you submit, `$_POST` is empty? thats weird

Comment: the print code u said put in, did you miss off the _ between the $ and POST?, I tried it with both still no values

Comment: @user3370876 thats just a typo, thats odd, after submission, the `$_POST` should at least print `print_r($_POST)`

Comment: it seems as if the value (value="<?php echo $row['memberid']; ?>") isnt being passed to the (name="delete[]")

Comment: @user3370876 try to check the browser console (F12) and check the DOM created by the loop, that code i just assumed that it is indeed `memberid`

Comment: by adding formmethod="post" and formaction to the submit button im now getting a print Array ( [0] => 166 ) user has been deleted.

Comment: its now working, thankyou for your help, it helps having someone to just get the brain to consider other solutions and of course you learn that way, many thanks

Comment: @user3370876 what thats the only reason why its not working? haha! okay sure im glad it worked and helped you